# Algorithm complexity of create array with size N with unique elements from N arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, recursion, rust, time-complexity

There are 2-dimentional array `A[n][m]` where `n = 2*m`.

Each array `A[i]` contains `m` unique integers in `[0;n)`. Note, that elements in `A[i]` and `A[j]` can intersect if `i != j`. Each array `A[i]` is sorted.

**Task**: construct array `B[n]` that contains unique elements by taking only one element from each array of `A`. Or there is not solution if `B[n]` can't construct.

Example:

```
A[0] = {0, 2}
A[1] = {1, 2}
A[2] = {0, 3}
A[3] = {0, 3}

Result: 
Take A[0][1], A[1][0], A[2][0], A[3][1] => B = {2, 1, 0, 3}
```

I have a recursive algorithm that solves the task:

```rust
// level = 0 at first call
fn recursive_choice(a: &mut Vec<Vec<usize>>, b: &mut Vec<usize>, level: usize) {
    if level >= a.len() {
        return;
    }

    for idx in 0..a[level].len() {
        if !b.contains(&a[level][idx]) {
            b.push(a[level][idx]);
            recursive_choice(a, b, level + 1);

            if a.len() == b.len() {
                return;
            } else {
                b.pop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better algorithm - and what is it? What is the complexity of this algorithm in the worst case?

Comment: "Is there a better algorithm" - define "better". By wrost case complexity? Average case? Best case? Actual speed? Memory usage?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, "better" means speed. I think the time complexity is `m^n` but at the same time I think that condition "`m` unique integers in `[0;n)`" can reduce the time complexity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be viewed as the problem of finding a maximum matching between arrays and values.  If the matching includes all arrays, then you have your answer.  If it does not, then the answer is no.

Which can be solved by standard approaches such as [the Blossom Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm) in time `O(n^4)`.  If you're willing to use a more complex and optimized algorithm, you can reduce that to `O(n^3)`.

Comment: Good answer, but this is a bipartite graph so we can use a more efficient approach to find the maximum matching, say Hopcroft-Karp for O(|E| * sqrt |V|).

Comment: @Dave And there are `O(n^2)` edges and `O(n)` vertices, which makes it `O(n^3)`. As I indicated was possible.  That said, naming one of the algorithms that do that is good information.

Comment: It's E sqrt v so O(n^2.5), marginally better.

Comment: Oops, you're right.